# Subquery with NOT IN - timeout in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a problem with a subquery in MySQL. The query runs into timeout:

```
SELECT mac FROM cc_btdata WHERE DATE(time)="2014-09-29" AND mac NOT IN (
SELECT mac FROM cc_btdata WHERE DATE(time) BETWEEN ("2014-09-29" - INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND ("2014-09-29" - INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY mac) GROUP BY mac
```

When I call the queries one by one it works. But not when i call them as subquery. I have also tried the queries in MariaDB on my Development environment and it works but not in MySQL.

What's wrong with this query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the query like this:

```
SELECT mac 
FROM cc_btdata b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM cc_btdata b2
                  WHERE b.mac = b2.mac AND
                        time >= '2014-09-29' - INTERVAL 60 DAY AND
                        time < '2014-09-29' - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                 ) AND
       time >= '2014-09-29' and time < '2014-09-29' + interval 1 day;
```

For performance, you want an index on `cc_btdata(mac, time)`.  I rewrote the date comparisons without `date()`, so MySQL will be able to take advantage of the index.

You could also write this as:

```
select mac
from cc_btdata
where time >= '2014-09-29' - INTERVAL 60 DAY 
group by mac
having sum(date(time) = '2014-09-29') > 0 and
       sum(date(time) between '2014-09-29' - interval 60 DAY and '2014-09-29' - interval 1 day) = 0;
```

(I used the original expressions for the `having` clause because MySQL cannot take advantage of indexes for the `having` clause.)  The first version will probably have better performance.

Comment: Thank you - your second code works great and very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need for `GROUP BY mac` and also you may consider replacing `NOT IN` with `NOT EXISTS` like

```
SELECT mac 
FROM cc_btdata 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM cc_btdata 
WHERE DATE(time) BETWEEN ('2014-09-29' - INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
AND ('2014-09-29' - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) 
AND DATE(time)='2014-09-29'
```

You may also like post the query execution plan (OR) explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

I think an outer join would work in this case and would avoid the dependent subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mac
FROM cc_btdata
LEFT JOIN cc_btdata cc_btdata_check ON 
cc_btdata.mac = cc_btdata_check.mac 
AND DATE(cc_btdata_check.time) 
BETWEEN ("2014-09-04" - INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND ("2014-09-04" - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE DATE(cc_btdata.time)="2014-09-04"
AND cc_btdata_check IS NULL
```